Help Understanding the Weak Equation for Fully Developed Flow (Inlet) in COMSOL
I'm working on a simulation in COMSOL Multiphysics and trying to understand the Fully Developed Flow (Inlet) boundary condition. The documentation mentions:
The Fully Developed Flow boundary condition prescribes that the tangential flow component on the boundary is zero.
$$\mathbf{u}-(\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{n}) \mathbf{n}=\mathbf{0}$$
The momentum equation for a fully developed flow in the virtual extrusion of the inlet cross section can then be projected onto the inlet boundary with the following weak equation as the result:
$$\int_{\partial \Omega}\left(\left(L\left(-\mu\left(\nabla_{\mathbf{t}} \mathbf{u}+\left(\nabla_{\mathbf{t}} \mathbf{u}\right)^T\right)+\frac{\left(p+P_{\mathrm{inl}}\right)}{2} \mathbf{I}\right):\left(\nabla_{\mathbf{t}} \hat{\mathbf{u}}\right)\right)-P_{\mathrm{inl}}(\mathbf{n} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{u}})\right)$$
https://doc.comsol.com/6.3/docserver/#!/com.comsol.help.comsol/comsol_ref_fluidflow.29.12.html
However, I'm having difficulty understanding how the weak equation in the documentation is derived and what it represents physically in the context of the boundary condition.
Could someone explain the steps or reasoning behind deriving this weak equation from the momentum equation?

You state a formula, but there is no equation.

Separately, what is $\nabla_t$? The tangential component of the gradient?
